# Why am I catching the exception

Tags: java, exception

I am running the following code to try and read from a text file.  I am fairly new to java and have been practicing by trying to create projects for myself.  The following code is slightly modified from what I originally found to try and read a text file but for some reason it catching the exception every time.  The text file that it is trying to read from only says "hello world".  I assume it must not be finding the text file.  I put it in the same folder as the source code and it appears in the source packages (I'm using netbeans btw).  It probably just needs to be imported differently but I can't find any further info on it.  In case my code is relevant  here it is below.

```
package stats.practice;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public final class TextCompare {

    String NewString;

    public static void main() {
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("hello.txt"));
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(str);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } 
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step, replace below code

```
catch (IOException e){}
```

with

```
catch ( IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

and also replace

```
main()
```

with

```
main(String[] args)
```

This will tell you the exact reason. and then you have to solve the actual reason.

Now for Netbeans, the file `hello.txt` has to be in your Netbeans project. like

```
<project_dir>
    |
    -->hello.txt
    -->build
    -->src
```

Comment: Thank you.  Replacing the location of the text file was all it needed.

Answer (score 7):

The closing brace in the `catch` block is misplaced. Move it to be below the `System.out.println("Error");`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("hello.txt"));
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) { // <-- from here
        System.out.println("Error");
        // or even better
        e.printStackTrace();
    } // <-- to here
}
```

As a matter of defensive programming (pre-Java 7 at least) you should always close resources in a `finally` block:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("hello.txt"));
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }

        // or if you're using Google Guava, it's much cleaner:
        Closeables.closeQuietly(in);
    }
}
```

If you are using Java 7, you can take advantage of automatic resource management via [`try`-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("hello.txt"))) {
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it should print something better than error so you can see what the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't necessarily catching the exception every time. Your `System.out.println("Error");` statement is outside of the catch block. Therefore, it is executed every time the program executes.

To fix this, move it within the braces (`catch (IOException e) {System.out.println("Error");}`)

Answer (score 1):

You have an empty catch block which is almost always a bad idea. Try putting this there:

```
... catch (IOException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

And you should quickly see what's going on.